Get the contents of a variable from an external file and display the contents
The file versionen.php is in the "dataplace" folder in all defined domain-accounts.
I would like to use the following script to read and output the $software_version variable for all defined domains on an external domain.
The $software_version variable is in the versionen.php file and is also displayed correctly locally.
The URL is loaded correctly, which is also displayed correctly by the Else branch of if ($content === false) {.
The domains are displayed correctly in the test output, but "Software-Empty" is always displayed for "$version".
I just can't get the content of the "$software_version" variable to work.
What have I not taken into account? What needs to be changed/added?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// FTP-Zugangsdaten für alle URLs (1 bis x) | FTP access data for all URLs (1 to x)
$ftpCredentialsList = array(
    1 => array("hostname" => "url-1.tld", "username" => "xxxxxxxx", "password" => "yyyyyyyy"),
    2 => array("hostname" => "url-2.tld", "username" => "xxxxxxxx", "password" => "yyyyyyyy"),
    3 => array("hostname" => "url-3.tld", "username" => "xxxxxxxx", "password" => "yyyyyyyy"),
    4 => array("hostname" => "url-4.tld", "username" => "xxxxxxxx", "password" => "yyyyyyyy"),
    5 => array("hostname" => "url-5.tld", "username" => "xxxxxxxx", "password" => "yyyyyyyy"),
);

########## Software-Release ##########

// Funktion, um die Software-Version einer URL abzurufen | Function to retrieve the software version of a URL
function getSoftwareVersion($url) {
    // cURL-Verbindung erstellen | Create cURL connection
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    // Optionen für cURL festlegen | Setting options for cURL
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Folge Umleitungen | Follow redirects

    // Inhalt der Datei abrufen | Retrieve file contents
    $content = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($content === false) {
        die("Fehler beim Abrufen der Software-Version für $url: " . curl_error($curl)"| Error retrieving software version for $url: " . curl_error($curl));
    } else {
        // echo 'Abruf der Software-Version für '.$url.' war erfolgreich. | Retrieving the software version for '.$url.' was successful.<br>';
    }

    // Die Variable $software_version aus dem Inhalt extrahieren | Extract the variable $software_version from the content
    preg_match('/\$software_version\s*=\s*(.*?);/i', $content, $matches);
    $softwareVersion = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : null;

// Debugging-Ausgabe | Debugging output
echo "Regex-Matches: ";
var_dump($matches);
echo "<br>";

echo "Software-Version: ";
var_dump($softwareVersion);
echo "<br>";
// Ende Debugging

    curl_close($curl);

    return $softwareVersion;
}

// Ergebnisse speichern | Save results
$softwareVersions = array();

foreach ($ftpCredentialsList as $index => $ftpCredentials) {
    $url = "https://{$ftpCredentials['hostname']}/dataplace/versionen.php";
    $softwareVersion = getSoftwareVersion($url);

    // Überprüfen, ob die Software-Version gültig ist, bevor Farbe zugewiesen wird
    // Check if the software version is valid before assigning color
    $colorClass = 'software_empty'; // Standardfarbe, wenn die Software-Version leer ist | Default color if the software-version is empty
    if ($softwareVersion !== null) {
        $colorClass = (stripos($softwareVersion, 'software_red') !== false ? 'software_red' : 'software_green');
    }

    // Ergebnisse in Array speichern | Save results in array
    $softwareVersions[$ftpCredentials['hostname']] = (empty($softwareVersion) ? "Software-Empty" : htmlspecialchars($softwareVersion));

    // Farbinformationen zusätzlich speichern | Store additional color information
    $softwareVersions['color'][$ftpCredentials['hostname']] = $colorClass;
}

// Testausgabe | Test issue
foreach ($softwareVersions as $hostname => $version) {
    if (!is_array($version)) { // Überprüfen, ob $version kein Array ist | Check if $version is not an array
        echo "<b>Hostname: <span style=\"color: #00F;\">$hostname</span> > Software-Version: <span style=\"color: #00F;\">$version</span><br>";
    }
}


you are trying to scrap the php file like its plaintext but that is most likely not the case, aka the file gets interpreted by php and output something else then you expect

Inspect $content

A var_dump outputs NULL. What would be the correct solution for my issue?

I’m honestly not aware that curl_exec can return null, but I don’t use it too much. An empty string, yes, but not null. It might help to reframe your question with that information.

It sounds like you are trying to get the source code of those PHP scripts? But you won't get the source code, when you request this via HTTP(S), and the target server sends the file through the PHP parser - you only get the output the script creates. Were you perhaps supposed to use FTP instead of HTTP? I mean, you are looping over a variable named $ftpCredentialsList, which contains not only host names, but also credentials (presumably FTP credentials) ...?
